# Can subscribers see commits from my branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket

In git, can I work on a branch without notifying the subscribers to the repository every time I commit something ?

Comment: Do you must have a remote branch ?

Answer (score 1):

in Git, it is easy to have a branch locally (on your machine) that is not yet pushed to the server (say GitHub for example).

on this branch, you can commit as often as you'd like, and not push to the server, so no other users will be notified of your commits until you decide to push.

however, this gives you the danger of "if your PC dies before you push, then you've lost your work."  because you have not yet pushed it to the server where backups happen.

you COULD also establish another remote location for your branches, such as a fork, but I think you might need to gain a bit more Git experience before looking into that.

EDIT: here is a video on YouTube that might provide a bit of context.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZY74CgynYA